# Get Grid Column value from Jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I tried to get column values from JqGrid. But it not possible. Any one can help is pleasure.

`var age = $("#list").find(columnName).html();`

This shows as Undefined..

Comment: Why aren't you using the jQgrid `getCell` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `getCol` method (for example in the simplest form of usage: `$("#list").jqGrid("getCol", "columnName")`). It allows you to get an array of values from the specified column of the grid or to get an array of objects with `id` and `value` properties. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `id` of the seleted row first, use that rowId in the to getCell that will use that id to get the value of the cell for you.

The code looks like this:

```
var myGrid = $('#list');
var rowID = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var cellVal = myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', rowID, 'colName');
```

Where `colName` is the name of column for which you want to find value for that, which you gave to your column in the colModel.

If you need more than one columns value than you can get whole row data based on rowID and get column value from it using column name as shown below :

```
var row = myGrid.jqGrid ('getRowData', rowID); // This will return whole row data (or all columns value) 
var columnVal = row["ColumnName"]; // ColumnName is again name of column define in colModel array.
```

May this help you.

Comment: I'm use 
var cellVal = grid.jqGrid('getCell', 1, columnName);
but the result is not shown. it is take false ??

Comment: pls check rowID, i think it is not 1.

Comment: No this is default one i had add for the testing purpose

Comment: can you able to create fiddle for it ?